# Binding JComboBox to a JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jcombobox

I wrote this program that has a JComboBox with items that represent Tables in my database, each item is supposed to display it's content as they are in the database on a JTable when selected. I've run the program, but when I select the combo box items, only the first items in the comboBox display its contents on the JTable, subsequent selections aren't displaying anything. Could someone please take a look at it and tell me what am not doing right? or advice me on any useful tutorial? I will really appreciate ur help, thanks in advance!

```
public class InventoryItems extends javax.swing.JFrame {
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private Object[] comboItems = new phoneClass().phoneManufacturerArray();
private JComboBox phoneBrandCombo = new JComboBox(comboItems);
private JPanel brandPane;
private JPanel instructionPane;
private JLabel instruction, brandLabel;
private JScrollPane scrollPane;
private JTable table;
private Object sel;
private Connection con;
private Statement stm;
private ResultSet rset;
private ResultSetMetaData meta;

/**
* Auto-generated main method to display this JFrame
*/
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            /**
             * Add a Look&F to the GUI
             */
            try{
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.jtattoo.plaf.aluminium.AluminiumLookAndFeel");
             } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                  java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(LoginInterface.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
              } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
                  java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(LoginInterface.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
              } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                  java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(LoginInterface.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
              } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                  java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(LoginInterface.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
              }
            InventoryItems inst = new InventoryItems();
            inst.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            inst.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

public InventoryItems() {
    super();
    initGUI();
}

private void initGUI() {
    try {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        /**
         * rows and column names declared as vectors.
         */
         final Vector columnNames = new Vector();
         final Vector data = new Vector();
          sel = phoneBrandCombo.getSelectedItem();

           //Get Selected Items and retrieve contents based on selected Item.

           try{
               try{
                  Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
                 }catch(ClassNotFoundException cnf){
                  System.out.println("Class Not Found Exception: "+cnf);
                 }catch(IllegalAccessException iaE){
                  System.out.println("Illegal Access Exception: "+iaE);
                 }catch(InstantiationException iE){
                  System.out.println("Instantiation Exception: "+iE);
                }
                 con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/"
                    + "phoneshopsystem", dbLogin.dbUser(), dbLogin.dbPwd());
                 String query = "SELECT phoneID, phoneModel, phonePrice, QuantityInStock FROM "+sel;
                  stm = con.createStatement();
                   rset = stm.executeQuery(query);
                 meta = rset.getMetaData();

                int columns = meta.getColumnCount();

                //Get Column Names

                 for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++)
                    {
                        columnNames.addElement( meta.getColumnName(i) );
                    }

                 while (rset.next())
                    {

                        Vector row = new Vector(columns);

                          for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++)
                          {
                            row.addElement( rset.getObject(i) );
                          }

                          //Fill JTable rows with database table rows

                        data.addElement( row );
                    }
                rset.close();
                stm.close();
                con.close();

            }catch(SQLException sql){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Table SQL Exception@: "+sql.getMessage());
            }

          /**
           * Initialise the Table with the rows and column names
           * retrieved from the database resultSet.
           */

table = new JTable(data, columnNames){
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        public Class getColumnClass(int column){
            for(int row = 0; row < getRowCount(); row++){
                Object o = getValueAt(row, column);

                 if(o != null){
                     return o.getClass();
                 }
            }
            return Object.class;
        }
    };

    /**
    * Table properties
    */
{
//table.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(534, 180));
table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_ALL_COLUMNS);
table.setGridColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
table.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
table.setSelectionBackground(new Color(248, 248, 248));
table.setSelectionForeground(new Color(51, 0, 51));
table.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(248,248,248));
}
    // Add Table to JScrollPane
{
scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(534, 189));
scrollPane.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(212,208,200));
scrollPane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(""));
scrollPane.setViewportView(table);
getContentPane().add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
}

{
instructionPane = new JPanel();
FlowLayout instructionPaneLayout = new FlowLayout();
instructionPane.setLayout(instructionPaneLayout);
instruction = new JLabel();
instruction.setText("<html><body><br><p>"
            + "Select The Phone-Brand e.g 'Nokia',"
            + " To View Inventory."
            + "</p><br></body></html>");
instruction.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", 3, 11));
instruction.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
instruction.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
instruction.setBackground(new Color(240, 240, 240));
instruction.setEnabled(false);
instructionPane.add(instruction);
getContentPane().add(instruction, BorderLayout.NORTH);
}

{
brandPane = new JPanel();
FlowLayout brandPaneLayout = new FlowLayout();
brandPane.setLayout(brandPaneLayout);
brandLabel = new JLabel("Phone Brands: ");
brandLabel.setEnabled(false);
brandPane.add(brandLabel);
phoneBrandCombo.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
            if(ae.getSource() == phoneBrandCombo.getSelectedItem()){
                phoneBrandCombo.getSelectedItem();
            }
    }
});
brandPane.add(phoneBrandCombo);
brandPane.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(240,240,240));
getContentPane().add(brandPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
}

pack();
setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
getContentPane().setBackground(new java.awt.Color(240,240,240));
setPreferredSize(new Dimension(550, 330));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You load your data to `Jtable` only once at constructing of that, and then you never do that, because of your `Jtable` doesn't update while you select another item in `JComboBox`.

Instead of using `ActionListener` on your `phoneBrandCombo` use `ItemListener` like next:

```
 phoneBrandCombo.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {

        @Override
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent arg0) {
            if(arg0.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED){
                Object object = ((JComboBox)arg0.getSource()).getSelectedItem();
                //loadDataFromDBToTable(object);
            }
        }
    });
```

here `loadDataFromDBToTable(object);` is method for loading  new data to your `JTable` for selected `object`.

Read about using [`JTable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) and [`JComboBox`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html).

Comment: Let me check the code again, I'll post a feedback when there's an improvement. I appreciate your comment, I really do.

Comment: I implemented what you suggested, but it appears am still doing it incorrectly. I've read a bit on JTable but it doesn't give any examples on how to implement what am trying to achieve. This is what i did:

Comment: It works alright now. I added an ELSE clause that kind of repaints the table when a different item is selected from the comboBox. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It Works alright with this:

```
phoneBrandCombo.addItemListener(new ItemListener(){
@Override
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent ie){
        if(ie.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED){
            selectedItem = ((JComboBox)ie.getSource()).getSelectedItem(); 
classes.loadTableData db = new classes.loadTableData();
db.loadData(selectedItem, data, columnNames);

table.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames));
  }else{
         data.removeAllElements();
         columNames.removeAllElements();
  }
```

} 
});

Comment: Please add additional information to your question, rather than put the additional information in an answer.

Comment: Your point has been noted! I've edited the post to an answer!